# Julia : random normal distribution

Tags: random, julia, gaussian

l want to generate random normal distribution between 0.1 and 0.3 using 
randn()  how can l use it ?

l tried this one but it's not working

randn(0.1:0.3,(3,1)) # (3,1) three lines and one column

Comment: This does not make sense, since the normal distribution has (in principle) infinite support. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is the bell curve, i.e. it has a non-zero probability of being any real-valued number. So it's impossible to generate normal random numbers which is only confined to a range [a,b]. At most you can have a truncated normal distribution, but this is different from being normally distributed. Did you instead mean uniformly distributed? Then that would be `rand() * (b - a) + a` as isebarn mentioned. You can do truncated normal sampling via rejection sampling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try doing

```
randn(3) * (0.3 - 0.1) + 0.1
```

random number in a range [a,b] is

```
rand() * (b - a) + a
```

Comment: The point is that this will *not* guarantee that the result is between 0.1 and 0.3.

Comment: Either one of us is misunderstanding the problem